# Displaying an image with annotation - python

Tags: python, image, annotations

I have some GeoTIFF images with a few points with X and Y coordinates. I wish to display the image with the points annotated as `+` or `x' overlayed on the image.

How do I achieve this using python?

Comment: Try the plotting library matplotlib, it can show images and make annotations pretty easily.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps by just creating a new image with annotation:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont    
image = Image.open("image.png")
draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font  = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 20, encoding="unic")
draw.text( (10,10), u"Your Text", fill=‘#a00000’, font=font)
image.save("out.png","PNG")
```

Found: [here](http://diekershoff.de/tobias/2010-07-27/annotate-text-to-images-with-python).

Comment: It is a good answer. However, I would like to display the image as well. I wish to save only if required (space crunch).

Comment: Hmm... got it. What when just replace `image.save` with `image.show()` ?

Comment: Does PIL support GeoTiff too? I am sorry I cannot find the documentation to this PIL.